# Conversion from IplImage to Mat with cvarrToMat missing/skipping image data bytes

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm trying to convert an image from the container IplImage to a Mat object instead using [cvarrToMat](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#cvarrtomat)

I realized that the converted Mat image would display a number of random data bytes at the end (aka just some uninitialized bytes from memory) but I don't understand why this is happening and/or how to fix this? See the code and results below.

I'm using opencv 2.4.13.7 and working in Visual Studio 2017 (Visual C++ 2017)

I produced a data array with pixelwise recognizable data to contain data of a 3*4 resolution image with a depth of 8 bit and 3 color channels. When the data from the converted image is printed it shows that it skips a pixel (3 bytes) at each row end of the data.

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "cv.hpp"
#include "highgui.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
IplImage* ipl = NULL;
const char* windowName = "Mat image";
int i = 0;

ipl = cvCreateImage(cvSize(3, 4), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
char array[3* 4 * 3] = { 11,12,13, 21,22,23, 31,32,33, 41,42,43, 51, 52, 53, 61, 62, 63, 71, 72, 73, 81, 82, 83, 91, 92, 93, 101, 102, 103, 111, 112, 113, 121, 122, 123 };

ipl->imageData = array;

printf("ipl->imageData = [ ");
for (i = 0; i < (ipl->width*ipl->height*ipl->nChannels); i++) {
    printf("%u, ", ipl->imageData[i]);
}
printf("]\n\n");


Mat ipl2 = cvarrToMat(ipl);
cout << "ipl2 = " << endl << " " << ipl2 << endl << endl;

//display dummy image in window to use waitKey function
Mat M(3, 3, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0, 0, 255));
namedWindow(windowName, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow(windowName, M);

waitKey(0);

cvReleaseImage(&ipl);
}
```

Result:
[Console window output for 3*4 resolution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSFQ9.png)

If the same is done for only a 2*2 pixel resolution image then only two bytes are skipped at the row end.. I can not explain this either.

[Console window output for same code only with 2*2 resolution image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJ1ya.png)

The reason why I would like to do this conversion is because I have a working routine in C of importing image data from a file (long story about old image file formats with raw image data) to an IplImage for further processing which I would like to keep for now - but I would like to start processing the images as Mat as this seems more widely supported and more simple to use in general, at least until I saw this.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no OpenCV 2.4.xxx setup available right now to replicate your code. Instead of `cout << [...] << ipl2 << [...]`, could you please iterate all elements of `ipl2` and compare the values? We moved from OpenCV 2.4.xxx to OpenCV 3.4.xxx a while ago, and now to OpenCV 4.0.xxx with a kind of large project. We used `cvarrToMat` during the transition and could not observe any changes at all (with respect to the image data itself). Just wanted to say that to encourage you to move from `IplImage` to `Mat`.

Comment: C API is deprecated, and is encouraged not to use it.... It looks like the data is aligned somehow... Take a look to widthStep and align from IplImage.... My guess is that data is aligned to be base 2 per row .... probably 4x4 matrix do not show this error... As in the previous comment, I do not have 2.4 to test it with, but I think it is something like that. Also, the documentation says not to use ImageData directly but with setData....

Comment: @HansHirse Can you suggest a way to "iterate all elements" and display them rather than what I did? As you might have guessed I am new to the C++ API and what I did was just what was suggested in the doc https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: That is not an answer to the question itself, but should help the author to further investigate his problem. Also, see the comments beneath the question.

As a small test, I use this 3x3 image (you can hardly see - have a look at the "raw" input of my question for the link):

[image: Small 3x3 image]

In *Image Watch* (Visual Studio extension), it'll look like this:

[image: Visualisation]

Let's try the following code:

```cpp
    // Read input image.
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("test.png", cv::IMREAD_COLOR);

    // Output pixel values.
    for (int x = 0; x < img.cols; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < img.rows; y++)
        {
            printf("%d ", img.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x)[0]);
            printf("%d ", img.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x)[1]);
            printf("%d \n", img.at<cv::Vec3b>(y, x)[2]);
        }
    }
```

We'll get this output:

```
0 255 255
0 255 255
255 255 255
255 0 255
255 255 255
255 0 255
0 0 255
0 255 255
255 0 255
```

Now, you could use the nested loops to check, whether the image data (or better: the pixel values) are identical in your `IplImage ipl` and in your `Mat ipl2`.